# .net sdk on alpine linux

Tags: docker, jenkins, .net-core, alpine-linux

I'm looking to install .NET core sdk on alpine linux however I can't seem to get it to work.

For context I'm running alpine in a docker container where I have setup Jenkins. I want to build/test my .NET app with this container however the plugins don't seem to work and when I looked around the common solution was to just execute a commandline statement "dotnet restore" & "dotnet test".

To do this I need to install it on alpine.

Anybody have any experience with this problem? I'm fairly new to all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core on Alpine only [works in .NET Core 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-net-core-2-1/) and later. Do you have that version? If so, did you also consider the [official .NET Core Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/)?

Comment: Yes, I have trying to install the 2.1 version. I have also considered using the official  docker images however because I'm planning to use Jenkins to call them I started with setting up the official Jenkins image. I'm trying to install .NET Core 2.1 onto that image.

Comment: You could execute a step in your pipeline on the official .NET Core image. I have not used Jenkins in a while, but I think this works: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really think about launching a Docker container from a Docker container. I will check this out and post an update.

Comment: If that all doesn't work, you can find the official .NET Core dockerfiles here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/2.1 Which might gives you some pointers on how to install the correct dependencies and SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the references man! With this I'm sure I'll be able to make it work.